# Exclude API/login urls from router routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a React App which proxies requests to Django, and Django has allauth installed to manage social app login. But my app is SPA which uses react-router, so when I have a link like `/accounts/github/login`, it seems like it is only passed to router, not attempred to open correctly. How can I exempt some url mask from routing?

Comment: Check this article to help you setup protected routes (routerv4) based on authentication: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Comment: @AndreasT, this is about showing the link only to those who are authenticated, not about redirecting to another page from SPA

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand your problem correctly. Do you want to redirect to an external URL?

Comment: @AndreasT A URL on the same website, but not within SPA.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect a route (page-URL) of your SPA to another page-URL -out of your SPA- use this:

```
 <Route path='/login' component={() => window.location = 
 'https://example.com/somethingOutOfSPA'}/>
```

*works with router v3,v4